# iFrame and overlay div event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a extern iframe that I need to count views on.

I've tried overlaying a DIV

```
<div id="ad__video" style="width: 99%; height: 391px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; z-index: 999; background: #fff; opacity: 0;"></div>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

And bind a click on event upon it. It does trigger my div, but instead it does not trigger the click on iframe.

What is a Cross-browser solution to this?

Comment: Did you try `pointer-events: none`?

Comment: Yes but that doesnt trigger the div click event

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a cross-domain event from the parent page to the iframe using JavaScirpt.

If you want to count **views**, and not **clicks**, you can simply attach an onload handler to the iframe before the SRC property is set. When the iframe loads, the event will fire.

Comment: Is there no way I can accomplish this? any hack will do

Comment: @Diodeus's solution may answer your question.  The `onload` handler will fire whenever a new page is loaded within the iframe.  Or did you mean something different by "count views"?

Comment: No there is no "hack" around the same-origin-policy. It was put there to prevent the very type of action you propose. Pages would be hacking other pages and stealing people's data without the same origin policy.